# Cant get value of text area

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have used knockout and got these back from my ModelView template ...

```
<div class="both">
    <td>
    <h3 data-bind="text: MyText"> What type of fruit is healthy ?</h3>
    <textarea data-bind="attr:{id: Question}" class="my-response" id="1"> this is my text area value </textarea>
    </td>   
</div>

<div class="both">
    <td>
        <h3 data-bind="text: MyText"> What type of Veg is healthy ?</h3>
        <textarea data-bind="attr:{id: Question}" class="my-response" id="2"> this is my text area value</textarea>
    </td>
</div>
```

I want to get the value of text area and this is not working..

```
$('.both').each(function() {
 alert($('.my-response').val());
});
```

how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure about the HTML formatting?

Comment: You seem to be under-utilising knockout for getting your model information, despite using it to bind. Are you sure you need to collect this information with jQuery?

Comment: Bind your textareas with the value: binding, you do /not/ need jQuery to access the value!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function(){

   $('.both').each(function(index,item) {
       var v= $(item).find('.my-response').val();
       alert(v);
   });        

});
```

Working sample :  http://jsfiddle.net/2CGWG/3/

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one as well

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.my-response','.both').each(function(){alert($(this).val())});
});​
```

here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmPNQ/)

Answer (score 0):

This worked best !

```
$(function(){

$('.my-response').each(function () {alert($(this).val());});

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ameerkabeer/Y3UNg/)